# Can ADB protocol work in reverse direction?

Tags: android, adb

I know `ADB` protocol can be used to get shell to an Android device from a PC, but I want to ask if the reverse direction is possible. Is it possible to a get a shell to a Linux/Windows PC from an Android device via `ADB` ?